# How to run a python script with dependencies in the command line?

Tags: python, dependencies, command

I understand that you can run a python script from the command line by entering in the file name. What changes do I need to make with a file that has dependencies?

To be more specific, I'm using Pycharm with a specific Anaconda environment for a project. This environment has packages included such as tensorflow and keras. I can run it directly from Pycharm, however when I try to run from the command line, it gives and error saying that

"there is no model named 'tensorflow'"

What can I do to the command line to signal that it should be using a conda environment, let's call it Env1. I've tried activating the environment in the conda command shell and I still get the same problem. How can I address this?

Thanks

Comment: `conda activate env1`?

Comment: My understanding here is you have a Python program with tensorflow import, and you want to run it in the command line. For this I think you will have to convert your .py file to an executable (.exe file). Please try this and let me know. There are videos on YT showing you how to convert .py to .exe